# Get call back from Servlet in GWT when Upload file in SmartGWT's dynamic form without using DataSource

Tags: java, gwt, servlets, smartgwt

I am using SmartGWT Dynamic form submitForm() to implement a file upload functionality in the client side, here is the code:

```
final String DEFAULT_FILE_UPLOAD_SERVICE_PATH = "upload";
final String TARGET = "uploadTarget";

VLayout body = new VLayout();

uploadForm = new DynamicForm();

 // initialise the hidden frame
NamedFrame frame = new NamedFrame(TARGET);
frame.setWidth("1px");
frame.setHeight("1px");
frame.setVisible(false);

uploadForm.setEncoding(Encoding.MULTIPART);
uploadForm.setMethod(FormMethod.POST);
// set the (hidden) form target
uploadForm.setTarget(TARGET);

uploadForm.setAction(DEFAULT_FILE_UPLOAD_SERVICE_PATH);

// initialise the File name field
uploadItem = new UploadItem("filename");
uploadItem.setName("filename");
uploadItem.setTitle("File name");

// set the fields into the form
uploadForm.setFields(uploadItem);

// add the Upload Form and the (hidden) Frame to the main layout container
body.addMember(uploadForm);
body.addMember(frame);
```

And in the server side I have a servlet to handle the file upload request using Apache File Upload library, here is the code:

```
@Singleton
@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class FileUploadServlet extends HttpServlet {
    @Override
    public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        this.process(request, response);
    }

    @Override
    public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        this.process(request, response);
    }

    private void process(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        // check that we have a file upload request
        if (ServletFileUpload.isMultipartContent(request)) {
            processFiles(request, response);
        }
    }

    private File tmpDir;
    private static final String DESTINATION_DIR_PATH = "/files/upload";
    private File destinationDir;

    public void init(ServletConfig config) throws ServletException {
        super.init(config);

        tmpDir = new File(((File) getServletContext().getAttribute("javax.servlet.context.tempdir")).toString());

        if (!tmpDir.isDirectory()) {
          throw new ServletException(tmpDir.toString() + " is not a directory");
        }

        Log.debug("tmpDir: " + tmpDir.toString());

        String realPath = getServletContext().getRealPath(DESTINATION_DIR_PATH);
        destinationDir = new File(realPath);

        if (!destinationDir.isDirectory()) {
          throw new ServletException(DESTINATION_DIR_PATH + " is not a directory");
        }
    }

    private void processFiles(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) 
            throws ServletException, IOException {

        // create a factory for disk-based file items
        DiskFileItemFactory factory = new DiskFileItemFactory();

        // set the size threshold, above which content will be stored on disk
        factory.setSizeThreshold(1 * 1024 * 1024); // 1 MB

        // set the temporary directory (this is where files that exceed the threshold will be stored)
        factory.setRepository(tmpDir);

        // create a new file upload handler
        ServletFileUpload upload = new ServletFileUpload(factory);

        try {
            // parse the request
            List<?> items = upload.parseRequest(request);

            // process the uploaded items
            Iterator<?> itr = items.iterator();

            while (itr.hasNext()) {
                FileItem item = (FileItem) itr.next();

                // write the uploaded file to the application's file staging area
                File file = new File(destinationDir, item.getName());
                item.write(file);
            }

        } catch (FileUploadException e) {
            Log.error("Error encountered while parsing the request", e);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.error("Error encountered while uploading file", e);
        }
    }
}
```

With the above code, files upload works fine. My question is I don't know how to get the call back from servlet. One [tutorial](http://maryniuk.blogspot.com/2009/09/upload-file-in-smartgwt.html) says about using the hidden frame, but I don't know how to do that. Could anyone help me with this? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to write out a  tag as your server response, containing JavaScript code  which will execute inside the frame.  This code will need to navigate out of the frame to call some function you have put into the main page (eg top.someFunction()).  To set up the function in the main page, use JSNI to attach a JavaScript function to the window ($wnd in JSNI).

Note you don't have to do any of this if you're using SmartGWT Pro+ - this solution is just for people using the LGPL version.

Comment: Could you give me some details about writting JSNI method at main page? Like an example of the JSNI code in the main page and how to set it up and the corresponding JS code call back by server. Thank you very much.

Comment: Google has a ton of docs on JSNI.  Some techniques of going back and forth between Java and JavaScript via JSNI are covered in detail in this GWT blog post: http://googlewebtoolkit.blogspot.com/2008/07/getting-to-really-know-gwt-part-1-jsni.html

Answer (score 0):

I achieved to get a callback from my servlet in an alternate way without using JNSI.
I also use an IFRAME as target of the form so it doesn't open a new tab.

Basically it involves a table in a database to store the status of my action.
I use a timer that requests my table from an asynchronous call.

From the servlet side, it change the status of the entry created when it finished the job.

```
//My service creates an entry in my progressbar database
DelaiServiceAsync.Util.getInstance().launchProgressBar(
new DefaultAutoErrorHandlingAsyncCallback<Long>() {

    @Override
    public void onSuccess(Long pResult) {
    //gets the id from the entry created
    final Long token = pResult;

    //I give the token to the servlet so it can update the status of the entry
    tokenHItem.setDefaultValue(token.toString());
    tokenHItem.setValue(token.toString());
    importForm.rememberValues();

    // here you can show a prompt asking the user to wait. SC.showPrompt( ... );

    //form submitted to the servlet
    importForm.submitForm();

    //Timer setup
    //timeout after 5 tick
    final int size = 5;

    Timer timer = new Timer() {

        private int counter = 0;
        private String status = "started";
        @Override
        public void run() {

        // asynchronous call querying the table expecting a change of status
        DelaiServiceAsync.Util.getInstance().getProgress(token,new DefaultAutoErrorHandlingAsyncCallback<ProgressDTO>() {

            @Override
            public void onSuccess(ProgressDTO pResult) {
                status = pResult.getStatus();
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Throwable caught) {

                super.onFailure(caught);
                Log.debug(fonctionFormatee
                      + "::getProgress - Failure "
                      + caught.getMessage());
            }
            });

        if (counter == size) {
            //Timeout
            cancel();
            // we can clear the prompt here. SC.clearPrompt();
            return;
        }

        //check the status from my response
        //Here it says that my file has been written succesfully servlet side
        if ("written".equals(status)) {
            cancel();
            // we can clear the prompt here. SC.clearPrompt();
            //we leave the timer
            return;

        }
        else if ("error".equals(status)) {
            //Finished
            cancel();
            // we can clear the prompt here. SC.clearPrompt();
            SC.error("error");
            return;
        }

        counter++;
        }

    };
    //delay before the timer starts
    timer.schedule(10);
    //time interval between timer ticks
    timer.scheduleRepeating(10);

    }

    @Override
    public void onFailure(Throwable caught) {

    super.onFailure(caught);
    Log.debug(fonctionFormatee + "::launchProgressBar - Failure "
          + caught.getMessage());
     // we can clear the prompt here. SC.clearPrompt();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question but I'd like to improve @Charles Kendrick answer with sample code.

The SmartGWT [documentation](https://www.smartclient.com/smartgwt/javadoc/com/smartgwt/client/docs/Upload.html) explains different ways to achieve this, we're interested in this part

> **Background upload without the Smart GWT Server**
>
> Achieving background file upload without using the Smart GWT server is also possible although considerably more advanced. In addition to the steps above, **create a hidden**  element in the page, and **use DynamicForm.target** to target the form submission at this IFRAME. In order **receive a callback notification when the upload completes**, after processing the file upload, **your server should output** HTML content for the IFRAME that includes **a  block** which will navigate out of the IFRAME (generally via the JavaScript global "top") **and call a global method** you have declared as a callback.

On the client side

```
final DynamicForm frmUpload = new DynamicForm();
        NamedFrame iframeUpload = new NamedFrame("iframeUpload");
        iframeUpload.setVisible(false);
        frmUpload.setTarget(iframeUpload.getName());
        frmUpload.setEncoding(Encoding.MULTIPART);
        frmUpload.setMethod(FormMethod.POST);
        UploadItem itmUpload = new UploadItem("itmProveedores", "Archivo Proveedores");
        frmUpload.setItems(itmUpload);
        frmUpload.setAction(GWT.getHostPageBaseURL() + "api/catalogos/upload");
        IButton btnUpload = new IButton("Subir archivo proveedorees");
        btnUpload.addClickHandler(new ClickHandler() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(ClickEvent clickEvent) {
                frmUpload.submitForm();
            }
        });
```

for this to work, we need to register the callback method using JSNI, let's do that

```
private static void onFileUploadFinished(){
        SC.say("upload finished");
    }

    private native void registerOnFileUploadFinished()/*-{
        $wnd.onFileUploadFinished = @com.sample.CatalogosForm::onFileUploadFinished();
    }-*/;

...
/*on the constructor, load event or main entry point -it depends on your app-*/
public CatalogosForm(){
    /*initial setup*/
    registerOnFileUploadFinished();
}
```

finally, **on server side** we should return a script block to call the callback function. This implementation uses Apache CXF but the important part is to return the script tag to call the callback function

```
import org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.ext.multipart.Attachment;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

import javax.activation.DataHandler;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.ws.rs.Consumes;
import javax.ws.rs.POST;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.QueryParam;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Context;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MultivaluedMap;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.net.URI;
import java.util.List;

@Path("catalogos")
public class CatalogosREST {
    private final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(CatalogosREST.class);

    private String getFileName(MultivaluedMap<String, String> header) {
        String[] contentDisposition = header.getFirst("Content-Disposition").split(";");
        for (String filename : contentDisposition) {
            if ((filename.trim().startsWith("filename"))) {
                String[] name = filename.split("=");
                String exactFileName = name[1].trim().replaceAll("\"", "");
                return exactFileName;
            }
        }
        return "unknown";
    }

    @POST
    @Path("/upload")
    @Consumes("multipart/form-data")
    public Response uploadFile(List<Attachment> attachments, @Context HttpServletRequest request) {
        log.debug("se ha recibido una peticion para subir un archivo de proveedores [attachments: {}, request: {}]", attachments, request);
        Response response = null;
        for (Attachment attachment : attachments) {
            DataHandler handler = attachment.getDataHandler();
            try {
                InputStream stream = handler.getInputStream();
                MultivaluedMap<String, String> map = attachment.getHeaders();
                log.debug("headers: {}", map);
                log.debug("fileName: {}", getFileName(map));
                OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(new File("/tmp/" + getFileName(map)));

                int read = 0;
                byte[] bytes = new byte[1024];
                while ((read = stream.read(bytes)) != -1) {
                    out.write(bytes, 0, read);
                }
                stream.close();
                out.flush();
                out.close();
                StringBuilder scriptOnFileUploadFinished = new StringBuilder(
                        "<script type=\"application/javascript\">\n" +
                                "      window.top.onFileUploadFinished();\n" +
                                "    </script>"
                );
                response = Response.ok(scriptOnFileUploadFinished.toString()).build();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                String error = "Ocurrio un error al subir el archivo de proveedores";
                log.error(error, e);
                response = Response.serverError().entity(error).build();
            }
        }
        return response;
    }
}
```